# Why will a list will not be accepted as an argument in this class?

Tags: python, django

I have a class which expects a list as an argument. The issue is when I import this function and use it as an argument I get a `TypeError` or `ValueError`.

I have tried searching for this issue but cannot seem to find matching issues.

Code which is having issues:

```
from payroll.payroll import get_employee_names

class ManagerForm(forms.Form):
    names = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[get_employee_names()])
```

Function which is imported:

```
def get_employee_names():
    # place uploaded files into variables
    tips_file = 'media/reports/Tips_By_Employee_Report.xls'

    # get managers name
    df_employee_names = pd.read_excel(
        tips_file, sheet_name=0, header=None, skiprows=7)
    df_employee_names.rename(
        columns={0: 'Employee'}, inplace=True)
    df_employee_names['Employee'] = \
        df_employee_names['Employee'].str.lower()
    # data-frame to list
    employee_names = df_employee_names.loc[:, 'Employee'].tolist()
    return employee_names
```

I expect it to use the list which is returned at the end of the function to create a dropdown menu.

The main Error I am currently getting is: `ValueError at /select-manager-run-payroll/ too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

EDIT: Come to find out it expects a tuple as an argument.

Comment: `choices` should be either an iterable of 2-tuples or a callable that returns such an iterable.

Comment: Thank you very much. Title has been updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ChoiceField` [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) argument should receive list of tuples, not 1-element list of lists.

Rewrite `get_employee_names` to provide:

```py
def get_employee_names():
    # ...
    # expecting that employee_names is something like ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return [(name, name) for name in employee_names]
```

and in your form:

```py
class ManagerForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_employee_names())
```